# Unity c# Object reference not set to an instance of an Object ( Shooting Script )

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

public string Name;
public int RateOfFire;
int ROF;
public int Accuracy;
public int Ammo;
public Bullet Amunition;
public PCP shootingPoint;
[HideInInspector]
public bool IsActive = false;

void Start () 
{
    ROF = 0;
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void WeaponUpdate () 
{
    if(ROF != 0)
    {
        ROF --;
    }
}

public void Shoot()
{
    if(Ammo > 0 && ROF == 0)
    {
        shootingPoint.SendMessage("Create",Amunition);
        Ammo --;
        ROF = RateOfFire;
    }
}
```

}

"Note : PCP is shortcut to Prefab Shooting Point".

I got this error in the shooting method in the line "shootingPoint.SendMessage" I just dont understand why ? and I have the Components at the objects I placed in the shootingPoint and the Ammunation , so what is wrong ??

Here is an image to prove I attached objects :
[image]

Comment: You need to initialize it I guess.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?lq=1

Comment: This is not pure .net Iam using unity engine which you have to deal with in a different way .

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I read the first part but most of the solutions were initializing it , which I cant do it in unity or if I can its not like normal c# coding ( Example example = new Example(); )

Answer (score 0):

Either shootingPoint or Amunition aren't objects yet. They're the only two things on that line that could be causing an issue.

Comment: They are and I will ad the image to prove this .